# Цикл for в jinja

Tags: python, html, jinja2

Исправляю html из книги по обучению... Нужно чтобы выполнялось 5 циклов for а затем снова таких же 5 с новой строки (данные подставляются из таблицы sql при помощи питона)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот код

```
{% block body %}

<h2>{{ the_title }}</h2>
<table><tbody>

<tr>
        {% for row_title in the_row_titles %}

        <th>{{row_title}}</th>
            
        {% endfor %}
</tr>

<tr>    
    {% for log_row in the_data %}
        
            {% for item in log_row %}
            

            <td>{{item}}</td>

                
            {% endfor %}
        
    {% endfor %}
</tr>

</tbody></table>

{% endblock %}
</body></html>
```

Comment: Вы всё содержимое в один `tr` добавляете.

Comment: тогда оно в одну строку идет

Comment: Ну. Всё верно. В одну строку и идёт, потому что Вы в одну строку (`tr`) всё и добавляете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tr внутрь цикла надо перенести:

```
{% for log_row in the_data %}
    **<tr>**        
        {% for item in log_row %}
        

        <td>{{item}}</td>

            
        {% endfor %}
    **</tr>**        
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: понял,спасибо за помощь